# Imagick: unable to open tmp file

Tags: php, debian, imagick, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to convert my raw camera files (CR3) to PNG with Imagick in CodeIngniter4. This is the code where Imagick gets involved:

```
            // Remove duplicate slashes
            $current_file = preg_replace('#/+#', '/', $current_file);

            // Generate PNG (with Imagick)
            $im = new Imagick($current_file);

            // Reduce resolution
            $im->resizeImage(1920, 1280, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

            $im->setImageFormat('png');
            $new_file = preg_replace('/\.CR3$/i', '.png', $current_file);
            $im->writeImage($new_file);

            // Delete CR3 file
            unlink($current_file);

            return basename($new_file);
```

This is the error I get:

> ImagickException #435
> unable to open image `/tmp/magick-pW-nr5lm_d8hNVdf-Yzkcnxhd1nmmwnv.ppm': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924

On my development enviroment on Windows (with the Imagick libraries in the php folder of XAMPP) my code works. The same code on my Debian server doesn't tho. I checked and I installed the correct Imagick version for my PHP version. This is the path ($current_file) on Windows `C:\Users\user\ci4\public\/Photos/2020/11/28_11_2020/IMG_0019.CR3` and this on Debian `/var/www/ci4/public/Photos/2020/11/28_11_2020/IMG_0019.CR3` . I changed the rights correctly on both Photos and tmp folder. What could be the issue here? Thanks in advance